# Selecting Recent Rows, Optimization (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, select, filter

I would appreciate some guidance on the following query. We have a list of experiments and their current progress state (for simplicity, I've reduced the statuses to 4types, but we have 10 different statuses in our data). I need to eventually return a list of the current status of all non-finished experiments.

Given a table exp_status,

```
Experiment | ID     | Status
----------------------------
     A     |   1    | Starting 
     A     |   2    | Working On It
     B     |   3    | Starting
     B     |   4    | Working On It
     B     |   5    | Finished Type I
     C     |   6    | Starting
     D     |   7    | Starting
     D     |   8    | Working On It
     D     |   9    | Finished Type II
     E     |   10   | Starting
     E     |   11   | Working On It
     F     |   12   | Starting 
     G     |   13   | Starting
     H     |   14   | Starting
     H     |   15   | Working On It
     H     |   16   | Finished Type II
```

Desired Result Set:

```
  Experiment | ID   | Status
----------------------------
     A     |   2    | Working On It
     C     |   6    | Starting
     E     |   11   | Working On It
     F     |   12   | Starting 
     G     |   13   | Starting
```

The most recent ID number will correspond to the most recent status.

Now, the current code I have executes in 150 seconds.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM 
          (SELECT Experiment, ID, Status, 
          row_number () over (partition by Experiment
          order by ID desc) as rn
          FROM exp_status)
    WHERE rn = 1
    AND status NOT LIKE ('Finished%')
```

The thing is, this code wastes its time. The result set is 45 thousand rows pulled from a table of 3.9 million. This is because most experiments are in the finished status. The code goes through and orders all of them then only filters out the finished at the end. About 95% of the experiments in the table are in the finished phase. I could not figure out how to make the query first pick out all the experiments and statuses where there isn't a 'Finished' for that experiment. I tried the following but had very slow performance.

```
SELECT *
FROM exp_status
WHERE experiment NOT IN 
(
  SELECT experiment
  FROM exp_status
  WHERE status LIKE ('Finished%')
)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the status column is indexed, it might be worth trying to move the `status not like ...` condition into the inner select with the `row_number()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your requirement, I think your current query with with `row_number()` is one of the most efficient possible. This query takes time not because it has to sort the data, but because there is so much data to read in the first place (the extra cpu time is negligible compared to the fetch time). Furthermore, the first query makes a FULL SCAN that is really the best way to read lots of data.

You need to find a way to read a lot less rows if you want to improve performance. The second query doesn't go in the right direction:

1. the inner query will likely be a full scan since the 'finished' rows will be spread across the whole table and likely represent a big percentage of all rows.
2. the outer query will also likey be a full scan and a nice ANTI-HASH JOIN which should be quicker than 45k * (number of status change per experiment) non-unique index scans.

So the second query seems to have at least twice the number of reads (plus a join).

If you want to really improve performance, I think you will need a change of design.

You could for instance build a table of active experiments and join to this table. You would maintain this table either as a materialized view or with a modification to the code that inserts experiment statuses. You could go further and store the last status in this table. Maintaining this "last status" will likely be an extra burden but this could be justified by the improved performance.

Comment: Thank you for your tip-- I will probably stick with the row_number() approach then!

Comment: The major kill is with the `status not LIKE 'Finished%'` part of the query. Reducing the queried data set by filtering the **not finished** experiments before doing a `row_number()` over it might help.

Comment: @justCallMeBiru You can't know which experiments are finished and which aren't in the inner query, this is why we need the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

Consider partitioning your table by `status`

[www.orafaq.com/wiki/Partitioning_FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Partitioning_FAQ)

You could also create **materialized views** to avoid having to recalculate your aggregations if these types of queries are frequent.

Could you provide the *execution plans* of your queries. Without those it is difficult to know the exact reason it is taking so long

Comment: Partitioning seems interesting. I don't have execution plan privelages, but, like Vincent said above, the long time is probably just due to the large size of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your first query slightly by using this variant:

```
select experiment
     , max(id) id
     , max(status) keep (dense_rank last order by id) status
  from exp_status
 group by experiment
having max(status) keep (dense_rank last order by id) not like 'Finished%'
```

If you compare the plans, you'll notice one step less

Regards,
Rob.